# Как найти информацию про установленный пакет на Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, package, install

Доброго времени суток.

Вопрос довольно глобального характера. Я не могу понять саму концепцию.

Как найти информацию по работе установленного пакета? Где найти примеры использования? Где расположены в системе файлы, файлы с примерами, мануалы? Какие методы использует этот пакет, чтобы к нему обратиться?

На данный момент я представляю себе поиск информации так:

- Поиск на форумах и сайтах статей и вопросов от тех, кто уже делал похожий проект и устанавливал данные пакеты (оттуда и знание о существовании самого пакета)
- Stackoverflow
- Git репозиторий проекта и его Вики
- `apt-cache show [пакет]` - обычно лишь общие слова о работе пакета, которые я уже знаю
- `man [пакет]` - не работает, потому что нужно знать название методов данного пакета

В результате я получаю отрывки информации, нет полной картины. Я использую методы, какие озвучены, но не знаю о существовании других. Часто никакого Вики вообще нету..

А хотелось бы получить хотя бы название методов, чтобы дальше уже копать по ним, примеры использования. В идеале структурированную информацию о пакете

Для примера: установил я пакеты `sudo apt install zbar-tools python-zbar python-qrtools` - для распознавания qr кода на изображении или же `sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez blueman` (это для работы с bluetooth на Raspberry Pi). Я знаю о существовании мифического файла `blescan.py` с примером работы, но не могу найти его расположения.

Буду признателен за объяснения и разжёвывание общих принципов.

Comment: Документация на всё что угодно всегда хоть немного неполна, неактуальна, некорректна и самопротиворечива. :)

Comment: Добавте метку дистрибутива.

Comment: Еще плюс метка `-h` или `--help` при вызове пакета, но вообще смотреть код

Comment: @Shamil это общая проблема опенсорса. Все пректы GNU достаточно подробно задокументированы. Для себя, проблему с примерами я решил созданием проекта, куда добавляю записи из рабочего процесса https://github.com/Hellseher/cix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

начинать можно с просмотра файлов, входящих в пакет:

```
$ dpkg -L имя.пакета
```

---

например, рассмотрим пакет `bluez`.

исполняемые файлы обычно располагаются в каталогах, содержащих в пути строку `bin`:

```
$ dpkg -L bluez | grep bin
/bin
/bin/hciconfig
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/bluetoothctl
/usr/bin/bccmd
/usr/bin/btmon
/usr/bin/rctest
/usr/bin/hciattach
/usr/bin/hcitool
/usr/bin/sdptool
/usr/bin/ciptool
/usr/bin/l2ping
/usr/bin/l2test
/usr/bin/rfcomm
/usr/bin/gatttool
/usr/sbin/bluetoothd
```

видим ряд исполняемых файлов, начиная с `hciconfig` и заканчивая `bluetoothd`.

man-страницы обычно располагаются в каталогах, содержащих в пути строку `man`:

```
$ dpkg -L bluez | grep man
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/share/man/man8/bluetoothd.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/bluetoothctl.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/btmon.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/l2test.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/hid2hci.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/l2ping.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/rctest.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/rfcomm.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ciptool.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/hcitool.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/hciconfig.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/hciattach.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/bccmd.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/sdptool.1.gz
```

видим ряд man-страниц, начиная с `bluetoothd` и заканчивая `sdptool`. просмотреть их можно командами `man bluetoothd`, ..., `man sdptool`.

документацию (иногда содержащую примеры) можно отобрать по признаку «содержит строку `doc` в пути»:

```
$ dpkg -L bluez | grep doc
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/bluez
/usr/share/doc/bluez/README.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/bluez/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/bluez/changelog.Debian.amd64.gz
/usr/share/doc/bluez/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/bluez/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/bluez/copyright
```

нередко, если документации много, её выделют в отдельный пакет, имя которого заканчивается суффиксом `-doc` (а иногда ещё и с дополнительным разбиением на языки, с добавлением суффикса `-язык`). например, документация к пакету `aptitude` содержится в таких пакетах:

```
$ apt-cache search aptitude doc
aptitude-doc-cs - Czech manual for aptitude, a terminal-based package manager
aptitude-doc-en - English manual for aptitude, a terminal-based package manager
aptitude-doc-es - Spanish manual for aptitude, a terminal-based package manager
aptitude-doc-fi - Finnish manual for aptitude, a terminal-based package manager
aptitude-doc-fr - French manual for aptitude, a terminal-based package manager
aptitude-doc-it - Italian manual for aptitude, a terminal-based package manager
aptitude-doc-ja - Japanese manual for aptitude, a terminal-based package manager
aptitude-doc-ru - Russian manual for aptitude, a terminal-based package manager
```

Comment: @alexander_barakin Проблема новых пакетов - это небрежное отношение к документации в целом. Разработчики очень быстро сменяют друг друга и поддерживать документацию становится практически невозможно. Даже при наличии man страницы, найти примеры пользования, порой, бывает очень проблематично. Из древних пакетов lsof содержит отличные примеры прям в man так же, как и многие пакеты GNU.

Comment: @Hellseher, вы совершенно правы, но к вопросу это, мне кажется, вряд ли относится, ведь вопрос, насколько я понял, про то, как найти то, что **есть**, а не то, чего **нет**.